# ordering the images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have some images and I need to order them in different types in a wpf window. as the image could not to be added directly to the window I used the stack panel. my final result must be some like what is shown in this figure. 
[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  What have you tried so far.  Please post some code or XAML showing what you have tried and what did not work for you.  As your question currently stands, it will probably be closed as 'too broad' since it doesn't include enough information for people to try to help with your problem.

Comment: hi, itried to put images in stackpanel but the images were placed in one direction, vertical or horizontal based on the stack panel's orientation where as in my case i need to put some images vertically side y side and some horizontally and some images must be on top of other images like what is numbered in the images that i have uploaded.

Comment: Use either a Grid or a Canvas instead of a Stackpanel.  Either of those two controls will give you more control than the Stackpanel.

Comment: can you provide a sample code (not XAML) that can show two vertical parallel images that another image is placed on top of them horizontally just like H.. thanks